# ExFat mount permission

Tags: ubuntu, fstab, exfat

I am trying to mount an exfat drive using fstab with read/write permission for both user and group.
The line of `etc/fstab` for this drive is:

```bash
UUID=5E98-37EA /home/ftagliacarne/data/media exfat defaults,rw,uid=1000,gid=1001,umask=002 0 1
```

Using these option the drive gets mounted to the correct location to the correct user and group, however, the group does not have read-write access. i.e. the permission are set to:

```bash
drwxr-xr-x 7 ftagliacarne docker-media 262144 Sep 24 20:40 media
```

Is there any way of setting the group permission to also have read-write access?

Desired outcome:

```bash
drwxrwxr-x 7 ftagliacarne docker-media 262144 Sep 24 20:40 media
```

Some of the things I tried:

- Setting `umask` to `002`
- Using `chmod` before/after mounting
- Using `chmod` recursively on the parent directory

Appreciate any help you can give me.

**Update 1:**

I also tried changing the fstab file to the following:

```
UUID=5E98-37EA /home/ftagliacarne/data/media exfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1001,dmask=0002,fmask=0113 0 1
```

Alas, it still does not work.

**Update 2:**

After having issues at boot due to the configurations above, I changed the `/etc/fstab` entry to the following:

```
UUID=5E98-37EA /home/ftagliacarne/data/media exfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1001,fmask=0113,dmask=0002,nofail 0 0
```

And now it works. I suspect the issue was with the `pass` option being 1, as changing that to 0 seems to have fixed it. Thank you to everyone who helped!

Comment: Are you sure your gid is 1001? Check with `Id -g`

Comment: chmod and chown will not work, period.

Comment: From the top of my head, i would suggest to use `udisks2` and set permissions there accordingly : http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html
You may need to enable *on boot* mounting in `/etc/udisks2/udisks2.conf`.  I didn't verify this, though.

Comment: Is user 1000 member of group 1001?

Comment: @sudodus yes it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chmod` and `chown` will not work for mounted fat32, exfat and ntfs-3g, period.

What you're looking for is `dmask=0002,fmask=0113`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, that also didn't work.

Comment: That absolutely should have worked. Please post the output of `ls -la /home/ftagliacarne/data` It works here on three different mount points.

Comment: For me this worked: `rw,nofail,x-systemd.automount,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro`. Make sure to set the appropriate user/group IDs (instead of 1000).

Comment: the answer from @goetz worked for me (all others did not)